# Python Turtle key bindings only working once

Tags: python, python-3.x, key-bindings, python-turtle

I was trying to creating a simple keyboard drawing program with turtle that saves your drawing for later, however when trying to use the key bindings to move around, I can only move once.

I am running Windows 10. I am writing this for a rendering engine I built called `Ren` that uses this file-format to render shapes.

Here is my code:

```py
import turtle
from tkinter.filedialog import *

s = turtle.Screen()
s.title("Ren Poly Editor")

t = turtle.Turtle()

fileName = askopenfilename()

with open(fileName) as file:
    rendataLayer1 = file.read().split("\n")
    rendata = []
    for i in rendataLayer1:
        if not i.startswith("#") and i:
            rendata.append(str(i.split()))

t.color("black")

for i in rendata:
    i = eval(i)

    print(i[0] + " " + i[1])

    if i[0] == "cl":
        t.color(i[1])

    elif i[0] == "fd":
        t.fd(int(i[1]))

    elif i[0] == "bk":
        t.back(int(i[1]))

    elif i[0] == "lt":
        t.lt(int(i[1]))

    elif i[0] == "rt":
        t.rt(int(i[1]))

def fd():
    distance = s.textinput("Forward", "How far?")

    t.fd(int(distance))

    with open(fileName, "a") as file:
        file.write("fd " + distance + "\n")

def bk():
    distance = s.textinput("Backward", "How far?")

    t.back(int(distance))

    with open(fileName, "a") as file:
        file.write("bk " + distance + "\n")

def lt():
    distance = s.textinput("Forward", "How much?")

    t.lt(int(distance))

    with open(fileName, "a") as file:
        file.write("lt " + distance + "\n")

def rt():
    distance = s.textinput("Forward", "How much?")

    t.rt(int(distance))

    with open(fileName, "a") as file:
        file.write("rt " + distance + "\n")


s.onkeypress(fd, "Up")
s.onkeypress(bk, "Down")
s.onkeypress(lt, "Left")
s.onkeypress(rt, "Right")
s.listen()

s.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call the `textinput()` method in Python turtle (or the similar `numinput()`), it undoes your `listen()` call as the window that pops up to take input becomes the listener.  Simply add another `listen()` call after each call to `textinput()` and things should behave as you expect.